# iOS UIView touchesBegan not getting called

Tags: ios

I have some UIViews:

```
Top UIView: MatrixViewController
---- Sub1 UIView
---- Sub2 UIView
---- Subx UIView
```

In each Sub views I have set self.userInteractionEnabled=YES. 
Each Sub UIView do get it's touchesBegan called...

But, when touching beside of any of the Sub views the TopParent's touchesBegan is not getting called?

AppDelegate:

```
...
self.matrixViewController = [[MatrixViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = self.matrixViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

The TopParent UIView is created in ViewController / viewDidLoad:

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
MatrixViewController matrix = [[MatrixViewController alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[self setView:matrix];
```

Thanks